# awk to match file 1 with file 2 and average field 7

Tags: awk

I am trying to match all the `file 1` names in `file 2` and average them if there is a match.  The field where the match will be is `$5` before the `|` symbol and the average is the sum of `$7` that matches `$4`.  Thank you :).

**file 1**

```
AGRN 
CYP2J2
```

**file 2**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    1   2
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    2   2
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    3   2
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571 AGRN-7|gc=61.2  1   148
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571 AGRN-7|gc=61.2  2   149
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571 AGRN-7|gc=61.2  3   151
chr1    60381600    60381782    chr1:60381600   CYP2J2-1596|gc=40.7 153 274
chr1    60381600    60381782    chr1:60381600   CYP2J2-1596|gc=40.7 154 273
```

**Desired output (tab-delimited)**

```
chr1:955543     AGRN-6     2
chr1:957571     AGRN       149.3
chr1:60381600   CYP2J2-1596     153.5
```

I have tried so far:

```
awk '
 FNR==NR{d[$0]; next;}          
 {                              
     for(k in d){               
         pat="(^|;)"k":";       
         if($5 ~ pat){
             print;             
             break;
         }
     }
 }' file 1 file2 > output.bed
```

The `awk` does run but the output file, as of now, is 0 bytes.  Thank you :).

Comment: What happened to `-7` in this line `chr1:957571     AGRN       149.3`. Also which field is the key $4 or part of $5 or both?

Comment: Why is the first line AGRN-6 but the second just AGRN ?

Comment: Why are you adding a colon to the pattern? there's no colon in file2 $5. Use `pat = "^" k "-"`

Comment: @karakfa part of `$5` is the key and `$7` makes up the average (149.3).  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script should look like this:

*test.awk*

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[ \t|]*"
}
# Read search terms from file1 into 's'
FNR==NR {
    s[$0]
    next
}
{
    # Check if $5 matches one of the search terms
    for(i in s) {
        if($5 ~ i) {

            # Store first two fields for later usage
            a[$5]=$1
            b[$5]=$2

            # Add $9 to total of $9 per $5
            t[$5]+=$8
            # Increment count of occurences of $5
            c[$5]++

            next
        }
    }
}
END {

    # Calculate average and print output for all search terms
    # that has been found
    for( i in t ) {
        avg = t[i] / c[i]
        printf("%s:%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[i], b[i], i, avg)
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
awk -f test.awk file1 file2
```

Btw, the third avg in your expected output is wrong. The output should look like this:

```
chr1:955543 AGRN-6  2
chr1:957571 AGRN-7  149.333
chr1:60381600   CYP2J2-1596 273.5
```

Comment: when I run that an output file is produced but it is also zero bytes.  Thank you :).

Comment: Is the original file tab delimited? I've added tab to the list of potential delimiters. Try it again.

Comment: The output that is produced is `chr1:60381600 CYP2J2-1596 273.5` the two lines above it are not matched.  File1 is just a list of names in a column. Thank you :).

Comment: Can you run it using the data you've posted here on stackoverflow? It works! If it not works at home, then you've posted wrong data here.

Comment: There was a space after the first line that was causing the `awk` not to see it.... thank you for all your help :).