# improve bash loop with awk split

Tags: bash, awk

The `awk` below improved by @hek2mgl runs, however it takes ~15 hours to complete.  It is basically matching input files that are 21 - 259 records to a file of 11,137,660 records.  It is a lot but hopefully it can be made faster.  Maybe If spilt `$5` on the hyphen `AGRN-6|gc=75` to `AGRN` - `6|gc=75`could speed up the process.  Not sure if the below is a start or not. Essentially what it does is use the input files of which there are 4 to search and match in a large 11,000,000 record file. Thank you :).

**input**

```
AGRN
CCDC39 
CCDC40 
CFTR
```

**file that is searched in**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    1   0
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    2   2
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75    3   2
```

**output** (`$4 $5 average of $7`)

```
chr1:955543 AGRN-6|gc=75 1.3
```

**awk**

```
BEGIN{FS="[\t| -]+"}

# Read search terms from file1 into 's'
FNR==NR {
s[$0=1]
next
}
{

# Check if $5 matches one of the search terms
for(i in s) {
    if($5 ~ i) {

# check for match
  if s[$5] exists 
  s[$5] {

        # Store first two fields for later usage
        a[$5]=$1
        b[$5]=$2

        # Add $9 to total of $9 per $5
        t[$5]+=$8
        # Increment count of occurences of $5
        c[$5]++

        next
    }
  }
  }
  END {

# Calculate average and print output for all search terms
# that has been found
for( i in t ) {
    avg = t[i] / c[i]
    printf "%s:%s\t%s\t%s\n", a[i], b[i], i, avg | "sort -k3,3n"
}
}
```

Comment: Best way to handle this kind of situation is to create a hash table
from the entries from the smaller files. Then read each record of bigger
file and decide if it is found or not. This will result in less memory
usage as well.

Comment: I can't figure out what it is you're trying to do.I think you may be relying on us having some information about some previous question - if so you should at least provide the link to that question but you'd probably be far more likely to get people to read it if you just make this question stand-alone. Also your awk code is buggy and will produce syntax errors - clean that up at least if we're supposed to get some information from reading it.

Comment: Here is the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736994/awk-to-match-file-1-with-file-2-and-average-field-7

Comment: @tripleee: please use the standard close reasons for this; 'because code reviews are not welcome' is not a valid close reason. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777)

Comment: @MartijnPieters So what do you suggest? MVCE? Or don't vote to close?

Comment: @tripleee: Vote to close with a standard reason. It could be too broad, for example.

Comment: @tripleee: but just because a post is on topic elsewhere doesn't mean it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplify:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {input[$0]; next}
    {
        split($5, a, "-")
        if (a[1] in input) {
            key = $4 OFS $5
            n[key]++
            sum[key] += $7
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in n) 
            printf "%s %.1f\n", key, sum[key]/n[key]
    }
' input file
```

Your code is broken because of the over-use of arrays, but mainly this:

```
FNR==NR {
s[$0=1]
# ^^^^^
next
}
```

Array `s` will only have a single key, the number "1" because for each line **you assign the value "1" to $0**. You should write

```
s[$0] = 1
```

Comment: Is there a key/k mismatch at the end there?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to hear what the speed is of the following, I'm not sure it will be much slower since it doesn't require awk to do anything clumsy but it still requires the number of input selection passes to complete. If you want to optimize it I think you need to use associative arrays and hash the input selection match to its own array. That way you can have it done in one pass over the file - though still the same amount of potential passes per line unless you can skip searching after the first match you may be slightly quicker. 
Input file: `select.txt`
Search file: `search_file.txt`
 
`while IFS= read a; do 
awk "BEGIN {cnt=0;var=0}{ if (\$5~ \"${a}\") { var=var+\$7;field4=\$4; cnt+=1; field5=\$5; }; } END{print field4\" \"field5\" \"var/cnt}" search_file.txt
done < select.txt`